# Decode error in python3 in Debian (UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position)

Tags: ubuntu, python-3.x, debian

I have problem with decode in Python3 script. I know that this problem has been discused but solutions I have found don't help.

Problem: I have xml in 'Unicode string' type (get from doc.toxml()) and it write to file. And I response error 'UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 723-727: ordinal not in range(128)'. If I encoding doc.toxml(encoding='UTF-8') and decode xml.decode('utf-8') same error.

Fragment 1:

```
    resXmlFormat = doc.toxml()

    doc = '<?xml version="1.0" ?><ROOT><param>123</param></ROOT>'

    file = open('/tmp/test.xml', 'w+')
    file.write(resXmlFormat)
    file.close()
```

Error:

```
    file.write(resXmlFormat)
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 723-727: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Fragment 2 (with encoded):

```
    resXmlFormat = doc.toxml(encoded='UTF-8')

    doc = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ROOT><param>123</param></ROOT>'

    file = open('/tmp/test.xml', 'w+')
    file.write(resXmlFormat.decode('utf-8'))
    file.close()
```

Error:

```
    file.write(resXmlFormat.decode('utf-8'))
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 723-727: ordinal not in range(128)
```

On my local Ubuntu that's OK. But on Debian server false.

Comment: Run with LC_ALL=C in Ubuntu error too. How can it affect the locale?

Comment: All Ok. Need add encoding in open function or open in byte view.